# When downloading source packages from ubuntu what is the difference between *orig.tar.bz2 and *6ubuntu2.3.debian.tar.gz

Tags: 12.04, deb

I'm taking a look at perl in the ubuntu packages and on the right panel under "Download Source Package" I noticed 3 files http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/perl

- [perl_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.3.dsc]
- [perl_5.14.2.orig.tar.bz2]
- [perl_5.14.2-6ubuntu2.3.debian.tar.gz]

What is the difference between the last two files?

Answer (score 1):

The `orig.tar.gz` is the original upstream source tarball. The `debian.tar.gz` contains the contents of the `debian/` directory, which describes how to build the packages that are created from the source package (which is all three of those files, together).